# jQuery hover function doesn't work…

Tags: jquery

im trying to make an effect to my HTML, and the effects seems not working

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("li a").hover(function () {
                $(this).css("color","black");
            }, function () {
                $(this).css("color","white");
            });
        });
```

Comment: Works just fine. Please provide a demo replicating your issue. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rjmmaG

Comment: You should include the relevant HTML too.  And explain what's not working.

Comment: Since the code posted demonstrably works, your question is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Check the browser's console for errors

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the colors in your code, be reversed? So the link changes to white when hover, and back to black when non-hover?

Else your code seems to work just fine:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("li a").hover(function () {
    $(this).css("color","white");
  }, function () {
    $(this).css("color","black");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Hover me</a></li>
</ul>
```

Have you remembered to include the jQuery library?